# Subsetting and row_binding by column values using tidyverse scheme

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse, tibble

I have a `data.frame` that I would like to subset (by rows) into (overlapping) "batches" and then `purrr:::map` those batches to a function. In the example below, `d` is the `data.frame` I would like to subset and batch:

```
set.seed(19)
n1 <- data.frame(c0= "N",c1 = rep("A",4),c2 = rep(c("i","j"),2), num = rnorm(4))
n2 <- data.frame(c0= "N", c1 = rep("B",6),c2 = rep(c("i","j"),3), num = rnorm(3))
y1 <- data.frame(c0 = "Y", c1 = rep("A",2),c2 = c("i","j"), num = rnorm(2))
y2 <- data.frame(c0 = "Y", c1 = rep("B",4),c2 = rep(c("i","j"),each = 2), num = rnorm(2))

d <- rbind(y1,y2,n1,n2)
```

Here is `d`

```
#   c0 c1  c2      num
# 1  Y  A  i -0.7447795
# 2  Y  A  j -0.2597870
# 3  Y  B  i -0.1830838
# 4  Y  B  i  0.5186300
# 5  Y  B  j -0.1830838
# 6  Y  B  j  0.5186300
# 7  N  A  i -1.1894537
# 8  N  A  j  0.3885812
# 9  N  A  i -0.3443333
# 10 N  A  j -0.5478961
# 11 N  B  i  0.9806622
# 12 N  B  j -0.2366460
# 13 N  B  i  0.8097397
# 14 N  B  j  0.9806622
# 15 N  B  i -0.2366460
# 16 N  B  j  0.8097397
```

The subsetting recipe is to

1. subset by `c0` --> giving groups `Y` and `N`
2. within `c0=="N"` subset by `c1` --> giving groups `NA`,`NB`
3. subset each of `NA` and `NB`  by `c2` --> giving groups `NAi`, `NAj`, `NBi`,`NBj`
4. row_bind `N?i` to `Y?i` and `N?j` to `Y?j` (where `?` is `A` or `B`) --> giving the final 4 data subsets

In R:

```
subset.Yi <- d %>% filter(c0=="Y"& c2=="i")
subset.Yj <- d %>% filter(c0=="Y"& c2=="j")

list(
  d1 = d %>% filter(c0=="N" & c1 == "A", c2 == "i") %>% rbind(subset.Yi),
  d2 = d %>% filter(c0=="N" & c1 == "B", c2 == "i") %>% rbind(subset.Yi),
  d3 = d %>% filter(c0=="N" & c1 == "A", c2 == "j") %>% rbind(subset.Yj),
  d4 = d %>% filter(c0=="N" & c1 == "B", c2 == "j") %>% rbind(subset.Yj)
) %>% 
tibble::tibble(batches = paste0("batch",1:length(.)),data = .) ->tmp
```

If matching by `c2` was not important I could do something like:

```
d %>% filter(.,c0 == "N") %>% 
  group_by(.,c1) %>% 
    do(batches = rbind(d[d$c0=="Y"],.)) -> tmp
```

but that's not quite it. Thank you in advance!
BTW, I know outside `tidyverse` this is doable but as I adopted `tidyverse` scheme for the rest of my code, I was hoping to stay consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works in this case (although, it would be great to see other possibly more general approach from others).

```
tmp <- d %>% 
  group_by(c2) %>% 
  nest(.key = c2) %>%
  mutate(c2 = map(c2,~ .x %>% 
                    filter(.,c0 == "N") %>% 
                    group_by (.,c1) %>% 
                    do(batches = bind_rows(
                      .x %>% filter(.,c0 == "Y") %>% select(-c1),
                      (.) %>%  select(-c1)  ))
                  ))
```

`tmp` here will contain the four subsets.  I could then do something like

```
tmp %>% unnest(c2) %>% .$batches %>% map(.,~sum(.$num)) %>% unlist
```

which gives the `colSum`of column `num` in each of the 4 subsets.

```
[1] -1.94302047  1.14452254 -0.08355576  1.62951506
```

Side note: unselecting `c1` is technically not necessary here but since I was row_binding such that a part of dataframe was ignoring the value `c1` (see above subsetting recipe and note `?`), the value of c1 was confused, so I removed it.